# How do you build oddjob on Ubuntu (classpath errors)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, classpath, mrjob

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and using [mrjob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) to run some Hadoop tasks on Amazon Elastic MapReduce. I'd like to use [oddjob](https://github.com/jblomo/oddjob) with it. oddjob is a Java package. I have not used Java in a decade, so I'm getting stuck what I think are relatively simple build errors (CLASSPATH and similar). Building oddjob gives:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat, compiling:(oddjob/ManifestTextInputFormat.clj:1:1)
```

I've messed around, and have not been able to get it working. The errors are, I suspect, basic enough that other folks on the web have not had a problem with them, so there aren't forum posts. Lots of people are using oddjob successfully. The oddjob documentation is lacking for simple issues like this, and there is no pre-built JAR file to download.

What I'm looking for are instructions for making oddjob build on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04. I suspect a lot of people could benefit from documentation like this. MrJob is mostly used by Python programmers, many of whom do not know Java.

I suspect if you have Hadoop and are using it, this will take you a few minutes time to figure out.

Comment: set your CLASS_PATH environment variable such that your `oddjob` can have access to its own classes and modules.

Comment: Download pre-built jar here: https://github.com/Yelp/oddjob/downloads